# iPhone - extend UIImage for custom drawing at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, subclass

How can I subclass and draw on an `UIImage` directly?

I tried extending it and draw on `drawAtPoint:` or `drawInRect:` using `CoreGraphics`, but the `image` is blank. And neither of the above 2 draw methods are called.

Please don't answer me that I can draw on the `UIView` because I need a custom runtime designed `UIImage`.

Comment: how about editing your question to show some code that demonstrates what you've already tried to do with "`drawInRect`" or "`drawAtPoint:`"?

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly stated in the `UIImageView` document:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> Subclassing Notes Special Considerations
>
> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display.
>   **UIImageView will not call drawRect:** a subclass. If your subclass needs
>   custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base
>   class.

Because telling you to use `UIView` instead is now allowed, I'll just answer that it's impossible to override `drawRect:` for `UIImageView`.